# How to intercept tab change for form validation

Tags: flutter

I'm building a complex Flutter input form where inputs are spread across multiple tab views.

I've just discovered that in Flutter if you switch tab views then the Form in essence forgets about the input controls on the previous tab view.

Is there a way to intercept a tab/tab view change so that I can inject a form validation on the inputs on he tab view that is about to go out of focus?  And if the validation fails then the tab change can be stopped.

I was hoping to find a event handler like...

```
onTabChanging(int oldTabIndex, int newTabIndex)
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is posible to intercept it, placing a `GestureDetector` on every `TabBar` element is going to absorb the event or if you just want to disable the *bar navigation* you can just use the `IgnorePointer` and then call `TabController.animateTo` to move if needed.

Doing so in that way may overcomplicate your code over time, there are other solutions, here you have one that uses the `InheritedWidget` to make the data persist over the rebuilds which what is making flutter *"forget"*, when elements leave the viewing area they are disposed (only the state if the element is not replaced and even if it is you can hold the instance with a key) and when reenter they are built again.

In the example there is a `on_change`, it works as you may expect but it can not prevent the change in tabs, it just notifies you of the change.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext _) {
    return MaterialApp(home: FormTabs());
  }
}

class FormDataState {
  String text_shared = '';
  String text_a = '';
  String text_b = '';
}

class FormData extends InheritedWidget {
  // This calls is "non-mutable" class, if
  // for some reason you need to change the data on a
  // rebuild, updateShouldNotify will give you the old widget
  final state = FormDataState();
  FormData({super.key, required super.child});

  static FormData of(BuildContext ctx) {
    final FormData? result = ctx.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<FormData>();
    assert(result != null, 'Ho No');
    return result!;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(FormData _) => false;
}

class FormTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  final forms = {
    'A': FormA(), // Not ideal but it is simple
    'B': FormB(), // Each gets rebuilt on a tab switch
  };

  FormTabs({super.key});

  @override
  State<FormTabs> createState() => _FormTabs();
}

class _FormTabs extends State<FormTabs> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(
      length: widget.forms.length,
      vsync: this,
    );
    _controller.addListener(
      () => _controller.indexIsChanging == false
          ? on_change(_controller.previousIndex, _controller.index)
          : null,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void on_change(int from, int to) {
    print('Tab change from $from to $to');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext _) {
    return FormData(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _controller,
            tabs: List<Widget>.generate(
              widget.forms.length,
              (i) => Text(widget.forms.keys.elementAt(i)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _controller,
          children: List<Widget>.generate(
            widget.forms.length,
            (i) => widget.forms.values.elementAt(i),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

These two forms are very simplistic, they are only meant to show a way to tie back to `FormData` as you can reach it from any point downstream that has access to the context.

```
class FormA extends StatefulWidget {
  FormA({super.key});

  @override
  State<FormA> createState() => _FormA();
}

class _FormA extends State<FormA> {
  final _tec_temporal = TextEditingController();
  final _tec_shared = TextEditingController();
  final _tec_a = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tec_temporal.dispose();
    _tec_shared.dispose();
    _tec_a.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    var ref = FormData.of(ctx).state;
    _tec_a.text = ref.text_a;
    _tec_shared.text = ref.text_shared;

    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: _tec_shared,
          onChanged: (value) => ref.text_shared = _tec_shared.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field Shared'),
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: _tec_a,
          onChanged: (value) => ref.text_a = _tec_a.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field A'),
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: _tec_temporal,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field Temporal'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class FormB extends StatefulWidget {
  FormB({super.key});

  @override
  State<FormB> createState() => _FormB();
}

class _FormB extends State<FormB> {
  final _tec_shared = TextEditingController();
  final _tec_b = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tec_shared.dispose();
    _tec_b.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    var ref = FormData.of(ctx).state;
    _tec_b.text = ref.text_b;
    _tec_shared.text = ref.text_shared;

    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: _tec_shared,
          onChanged: (value) => ref.text_shared = _tec_shared.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field Shared'),
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: _tec_b,
          onChanged: (value) => ref.text_b = _tec_b.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field B'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, decided to pass a VoidCallback function to each form so that validation could take place in each form and update the parent widget (which would then rebuild the tabbar).

```
class OuterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OuterWidgetState createState() => _OuterWidgetState();
}

class _OuterWidgetState extends State<OuterWidget> {

  void _updateValidation() {
    setState(() {
      // Update tabbar
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        InnerWidget(onValidate: _updateValidation),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class InnerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onValidate;

  InnerWidget({required this.onValidate});

  void _validate() {
    // Do validation
    onValidate();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: _validate,
      child: Text('Validate'),
    );
  }
}
```